# Geopandas Dataframe Points to Polygons

Tags: python, pandas, shapely, geopandas

I have a geopandas dataframe made up of an id and a geometry column which is populated by 2D points. I want to join the points for each unique id to create a polygon, so that my new dataframe will have polygons as its geometry. My code currently looks something like this:

```
polygons = geopandas.GeoDataFrame() 
for i in id:
    group = df[df['id']== i]
    polygon = {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': group['geometry']}
    polygon['poly'] = polygon
    polygons = geopandas.concat([polygon,polygons])
```

It creates a polygon but when I assign the new variable `poly` it says

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index"
```

which makes sense since it is still just a list of coordinates and not an actual polygon object. Does anyone know how to make this an actual polygon object that I can add to a column on a geopandas `df`?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 9):

I have achieved something similar with the `groupby` function. Assuming your points are actually Shapely `Point` objects, and are sorted in the right order, you can try something like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gp
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

# Initialize a test GeoDataFrame where geometry is a list of points
df = gp.GeoDataFrame( [['box', Point(1, 0)], 
                       ['box', Point(1, 1)], 
                       ['box', Point(2,2)], 
                       ['box', Point(1,2)], 
                       ['triangle', Point(1, 1)], 
                       ['triangle', Point(2,2)], 
                       ['triangle', Point(3,1)]],  
                     columns = ['shape_id', 'geometry'], 
                     geometry='geometry')

# Extract the coordinates from the Point object
df['geometry'] = df['geometry'].apply(lambda x: x.coords[0])

# Group by shape ID 
#  1. Get all of the coordinates for that ID as a list
#  2. Convert that list to a Polygon
df = df.groupby('shape_id')['geometry'].apply(lambda x: Polygon(x.tolist())).reset_index()

# Declare the result as a new a GeoDataFrame
df = gp.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry = 'geometry')

df.plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Great answer @atkat12. But according to your plot, last two box points should be (0,1) and (0,0):

> ```
>    # Initialize a test GeoDataFrame where geometry is a list of points 
>    df = gp.GeoDataFrame( [['box', Point(1, 0)], 
>                    ['box', Point(1, 1)], 
>                    ['box', Point(0,1)], 
>                    ['box', Point(0,0)], 
>                    ['triangle', Point(1, 1)], 
>                    ['triangle', Point(2,2)], 
>                    ['triangle', Point(3,1)]],  
>                  columns = ['shape_id', 'geometry'], 
>                  geometry='geometry')
> ```