# How to convert vector points to lines following a specific order -python

Tags: python, qgis, geopandas

I am working with a set of points that represent the different stops of a bus line. I have a `.csv` file that give the `stop_id`, `lon`, `lat`, `stop_sequence` (which determines the ordre of the stops along the bus line) and the `direction_id` (which is either 1 or 0 and represents the direction taken by the bus).

```py
        stop_id                 lat         lon    stop_sequence direction_id   geometry
231519  StopPoint:59:3730058    48.770247   2.348581    5        1  POINT (2.348581 48.770247)
231520  StopPoint:59:3730064    48.759449   2.369324    2        1  POINT (2.369324 48.759449)
231521  StopPoint:59:3730062    48.759647   2.365572    3        1  POINT (2.365572 48.75964699999999)
231522  StopPoint:59:3730068    48.752867   2.377503    0        1  POINT (2.377503 48.75286699999999)
231523  StopPoint:59:3730066    48.756454   2.374298    1        1  POINT (2.374298 48.756454)
```

I turned this dataframe into a geodataframe and converted the points to lines with a method found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104710/geopandas-dataframe-points-to-polygons).

It does not take into account the `stop_sequence` of the gdf though and I get the following result:

[image]

Which is not what I had in mind. I need the green points to be converted into a line that takes into account the `stop_sequence` order. 
What I need is a line between stop 0 to stop 1, stop 1 to stop 2, stop 2 to stop 3 and so on until the last stop of the line, for one direction_id and then the other.

Is there a way of doing so with python? I could also work with qgis but python would be preferable.

---

**EDIT:** Here's a simplified version of the code I used.

I showed -above- an example relative to only one bus line, I many more that I work with and each bus line is linked to a `route_id`.

The complete `gdf` is the following one:

```py
# Since I have to consider many bus line I thought it would be easier to first work with one of them: line_a.
test = gdf.loc[(gdf['route_id'] == 'line_a') & (gdf['direction_id'] == 1)].sort_values('stop_sequence')
test.head()

         stop_id         lat    lon route_id    stop_sequence   direction_id    geometry
494867  StopPoint:59:3730102    48.806131   2.472466    line_a  0   1   POINT (2.472466 48.806131)
246032  StopPoint:59:3730102    48.806131   2.472466    line_a  0   1   POINT (2.472466 48.806131)
233510  StopPoint:59:3730102    48.806131   2.472466    line_a  0   1   POINT (2.472466 48.806131)
246062  StopPoint:59:3730102    48.806131   2.472466    line_a  0   1   POINT (2.472466 48.806131)
246092  StopPoint:59:3730102    48.806131   2.472466    line_a  0   1   POINT (2.472466 48.806131)
```

And I then used the following code line to convert the lon/lat points into LineStrings:

```py
gdf2 = test.groupby(['route_id'])['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x.tolist()))
gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gdf2, geometry='geometry')

gdf2['route_id'] = gdf2.index #I added this line because route_id was the gdf index and I couldn't .loc[] with it.

             geometry                                         route_id
route_id        
line_a  LINESTRING (2.472466 48.806131, 2.472466 48.80...   line_a
```

And I finally ploted everything with:

```py
gdf2.plot(ax=ax, color='mediumaquamarine', alpha=0.7, zorder=0) # Plot of the LineString.
gdf.loc[gdf['direction_id'] == 1].plot(ax=ax, color='green', alpha=0.7, zorder=1) # Plot of the station stops.
```

Comment: If you sort you gdf by `stop_sequence` it should work as intended. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: @martinfleis I sorted  ```gdf``` by stop_sequence but still got the showed result.

Comment: Can you post here the actual code you have used (not just the link)?

Comment: @martinfleis Yes of course, I just edited my post.

Comment: `gdf2 = test.groupby(['route_id'], sort=False)['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x.tolist()))` works? On sorted gdf.

Comment: Adding the ```sort=False``` to ```gdf2``` don't change anything.